# Vuex actions object not returning data

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have in my store the following:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
state: {
    campaigns: '',
    currentCampaign: null
},

mutations: {
    GET_CAMPAIGNS(state, campaigns) {
        state.campaigns = campaigns
    }
},
actions: {
    getCampaigns ( context ) {
       return axios
            .get('/api/campaign/history')
            .then((response) => {
                context.commit('GET_CAMPAIGNS', response.data)
            })
    },
}
```

});

The issue is that the `campaigns` is still empty. Please, what I'm not doing right?

[image: dev tool snapshot]

[image: Current campaign]

In my component methods, I called the mutations like so:

```
markAsCurrent (campaign) {
            this.$store.commit('CURRENT_CAMPAIGN', campaign.id)
        }
```

but the `currentCampaign` state is returning `undefined`

Comment: What happens when you debug your mutation?  What value does `campaigns` have?

Comment: @DavidL I have  the screenshot of my vue dev tools. mutations is not showing at all.

Comment: Well according to your screenshot you're not even dispatching your action, so why are you surprised that your mutation is never committed?  Did you actually debug your action to make sure it is getting hit and your promise is resolving?

Comment: Do you see the request dispatched in the Network tab of devtools?

Comment: Thanks @DavidL Gimburg You were right, I was not dispatching the action. Working now

Comment: Now I have an issue on changing the `currentCampaign` state even when the mutation is committed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `actions` and not `mutations` to retrieve your data, you should be using the `dispatch()` function rather than the `commit()` function.

Actually, I would rather you to call the `axios.get()` from your `methods` than from the `store` itself.

```
markAsCurrent (campaign) {
  let campaigns

  axios.get('/api/campaign/history').then(response => {
    campaigns = response.data
  }

 this.$store.dispatch('getCampaigns', campaigns)
}
```

---

```
actions: {
 getCampaigns ({commit}, campaigns) {
    commit('GET_CAMPAIGNS', campaigns)
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't just add async/await. If you do and you are not targeting evergreen browsers your answer will break the OP's ES5 solution.

Comment: @DavidL I believe `export const` belongs to ES6. If he were to use ES5, shouldn't it be `module.exports` instead?

Answer (score 0):

> Change your actions into the below code:

```
getCampaigns ( {commit}, context ) {
      axios.get('/api/campaign/history')
        .then((response) => {
            context.commit('GET_CAMPAIGNS', response.data)
        })
}
```

> Then you have to call this actions from you component like this:

```
this.$store.dispatch('getCampaigns', passTheDataHere)
```

> Note: if you want to commit a mutation inside actions you have to use {commit} in arguments.If also you want to use state or getters then {commit,getters,state}

Comment: This is both unnecessary and does not address the actual problem. In addition, you've now imposed object destructuring for the parameter which is inconsistent with the OP's ES 5 code.